# Pex Regex Problems

Tags: c#, regex, pex

I am trying to generate inputs for a method that performs Regex matching.
I started by having code that does the following:

```
public bool patternMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    string regexPattern = Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace(@"\*", ".*").Replace(@"\?", ".");
    PexObserve.Value<string>("pattern", regexPattern);
    Regex regex = new Regex("^" + regexPattern + "$");
    return regex.IsMatch(input);
}
```

For performance issues I am trying switch away from `new Regex(pattern)`.
Instead I tried using `Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)`

The result is a `MissingMethodException`.

i tried looking for solutions online and found that the example on pexforfun.com has the same issues (http://www.pexforfun.com/Default.aspx?language=CSharp&sample=RegularExpressions)

Is there any solution to this problem?
I am not sure whether the improvement with `Regex.IsMatch()` will generate better results (fewer timeouts) but the "expensive" way is hardly generating useful input sets.

Alternatively: how can I convince Pex to work better/faster (i.e. not hitting boundary conditions) with `new Regex` expressions?

Comment: You don't have to switch from `new Regex(...).IsMatch` to `Regex.IsMatch` - they will *both* use the internal regex cache. In fact, the static method does exactly `new Regex(...).IsMatch` - see [the source code here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,51c9fa9eba2c7c8a).

Comment: thank you. It is still a shame that I cannot use `Regex.IsMatch(...)` though